# Logarithmic returns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Python pandas has a pct_change function which I use to calculate the returns for stock prices in a dataframe:

```
ndf['Return']= ndf['TypicalPrice'].pct_change()
```

I am using the following code to get logarithmic returns, but it gives the exact same values as the pct.change() function:

```
ndf['retlog']=np.log(ndf['TypicalPrice'].astype('float64')/ndf['TypicalPrice'].astype('float64').shift(1))
#np is for numpy
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Here is one way to calculate log return using `.shift()`. And the result is similar to but not the same as the gross return calculated by `pct_change()`. Can you upload a copy of your sample data (dropbox share link) to reproduce the inconsistency you saw?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(100 + np.random.randn(100).cumsum(), columns=['price'])
df['pct_change'] = df.price.pct_change()
df['log_ret'] = np.log(df.price) - np.log(df.price.shift(1))

Out[56]: 
       price  pct_change  log_ret
0   101.7641         NaN      NaN
1   102.1642      0.0039   0.0039
2   103.1429      0.0096   0.0095
3   105.3838      0.0217   0.0215
4   107.2514      0.0177   0.0176
5   106.2741     -0.0091  -0.0092
6   107.2242      0.0089   0.0089
7   107.0729     -0.0014  -0.0014
..       ...         ...      ...
92  101.6160      0.0021   0.0021
93  102.5926      0.0096   0.0096
94  102.9490      0.0035   0.0035
95  103.6555      0.0069   0.0068
96  103.6660      0.0001   0.0001
97  105.4519      0.0172   0.0171
98  105.5788      0.0012   0.0012
99  105.9808      0.0038   0.0038

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: I'm getting a lot of values in pct_change() and log_ret exactly the same, and a very few values which are slightly different. Would that be expected?

Comment: @AmanArora Yes, that's an expected behaviour. log return and gross return are very very close when your gross return is small, say less than 1%. It can be mathematically proved by 2nd-order Taylor expansion around 0.

Comment: @AmanArora BTW, log return has the desired property that it is additive over time (but not additive over different assets), whereas gross return is most appropriate when you calculate a weighted average portfolio return (that is additive over different assets but not additive over time).

Comment: This calculates the log twice, rather than using .diff ()

Comment: @poulter7 .dif() provides the absolute change between 2 rows. Also note that `np.log(df.price) - np.log(df.price.shift(1))`  is equivalent to `np.log(df.price / df.price.shift(1))`  (one log operation)

Comment: So I was doing the same thing, but I tried the above answer and got: `loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable log method`

Comment: It is crucial to mention prices here are assumed to be ordered from the oldest point in time to the most recent one, with oldest point in time at the top row .

Answer (score 58):

Log returns are simply the natural log of 1 plus the arithmetic return.  So how about this?

```
df['pct_change'] = df.price.pct_change()
df['log_return'] = np.log(1 + df.pct_change)
```

Even more concise, utilizing [Ximix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2592043/ximix)'s suggestion:

```
df['log_return'] = np.log1p(df.price.pct_change())
```

Comment: Maybe you can use np.log1p:

df['log_return'] = np.log1p(df.pct_change)

Comment: This is certainly mathematically incorrect "Log returns are simply the natural log of 1 plus the arithmetic return. "

Comment: What am I doing incorrectly? Or perhaps, what do I _mean_ to say?

Answer (score 41):

Single line, and only calculating logs once.
First convert to log-space, then take the 1-period diff.

```py
    np.diff(np.log(df.price))
```

In earlier versions of numpy:

```py
    np.log(df.price)).diff()
```

Comment: it works but shows PyLint message "Instance of 'ndarray' has no 'diff' member"

Comment: This highlights a change in the numpy API, .diff() is not available on the array itself in the latest versions of numpy. Instead np.diff is the preferred approach. Updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 12):

The results might *seem* similar, but that is just because of the [Taylor expansion for the logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series). Since *log(1 + x) ~ x*, the results can be similar.

However,

> I am using the following code to get logarithmic returns, but it gives the exact same values as the pct.change() function.

is not quite correct.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'p': range(10)})

df['pct_change'] = df.pct_change()
df['log_stuff'] = \
    np.log(df['p'].astype('float64')/df['p'].astype('float64').shift(1))
df[['pct_change', 'log_stuff']].plot();
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

@poulter7:
I cannot comment on the other answers, so I post it as new answer: be careful with

```
np.log(df.price).diff()
```

as this will fail for indices which can become negative as well as risk factors e.g. negative interest rates. In these cases

```
np.log(df.price/df.price.shift(1)).dropna()
```

is preferred and based on my experience generally the safer approach. It also evaluates the logarithm only once.

Whether you use +1 or -1 depends on the ordering of your time series. Use -1 for descending and +1 for ascending dates - in both cases the shift provides the preceding date's value.

Comment: This is interesting, there are two approaches here, `np.log(1+s.pct_change())` and `np.log(s/s.shift(1))`, which are equivalent, once the series crosses into negative territory the log returns start to make some sense again. Or `np.log(s).diff())` and `(np.log(s) - np.log(s.shift(1))`, which explicitly drop negative returns.