# How to transfer logReturns back to original prices with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Logarithmic Returns can be calculated this way in Python - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31287674

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(100 + np.random.randn(5).cumsum(), columns=['price'])
df['pct_change'] = df.price.pct_change()
df['log_ret'] = np.log(df.price) - np.log(df.price.shift(1))

df
Out[84]: 
        price  pct_change   log_ret
0  101.883151         NaN       NaN
1  100.535392   -0.013228 -0.013317
2   99.264907   -0.012637 -0.012718
3  100.234303    0.009766  0.009718
4   99.061180   -0.011704 -0.011773
```

For a given starting price, how can I get subsequent prices back if I only have the `log_ret` data available?

Pandas solutions preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at the definiton of the log return and solve this for the price:

```
df['price_'] = np.exp(df['log_ret']) * df['price'].shift(1)
```