# how to calculate monthly log returns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edewc.png)I need to construct two new variable: monthly log returns of TSX and BTC.
Hint: log return of each month is calculated with respect to the previous months values
using the log of prices, i.e. Rt = ln(Pt) − ln(Pt−1)
Alternatively, you can work with the percentage change returns

My TSX and BTC come from a data frame that includes 3 rows and 60 columns.

I have tried the following:

```
InputData['S&P/TSX Composite index (^GSPTSE)'] = InputData.pct_change()
InputData['log_ret'] = np.log(InputData.price) - np.log(InputData.price.shift(1))
```

but that did not work

Comment: please, show an example of your input and output dataframe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logarithmic returns in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31287552/logarithmic-returns-in-pandas-dataframe)