# Logarithmic returns in pandas dataframe groupby ticker

Tags: python, pandas

I like to calculate the *log return* based on stock prices (adjclose) for each ticker in a dataframe with several tickers and prices.

A sample of such a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
f = {'date': ['2020-11-25', '2020-11-24', '2020-11-23', '2020-11-25', '2020-11-24', '2020-11-23'],
         'ticker': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AIR', 'AIR', 'AIR'],
         'adjclose': [116.029999, 115.169998, 113.849998, 29.510000, 29.540000, 27.890000]
         }

df = pd.DataFrame(f)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

Dataframe df:

```
               ticker    adjclose
date                             
2020-11-25       AAPL  116.029999
2020-11-24       AAPL  115.169998
2020-11-23       AAPL  113.849998
2020-11-25        AIR   29.510000
2020-11-24        AIR   29.540000
2020-11-23        AIR   27.890000
```

Following the ideas proposed here [Logarithmic returns in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31287552/logarithmic-returns-in-pandas-dataframe/48539196)

1. I would sort the stockprices by ticker and date

   `df.sort_values(by=['ticker', 'date'], ascending=True, inplace=True)`

   `df`

> ```
>            ticker    adjclose
> date                         
> 2020-11-23   AAPL  113.849998
> 2020-11-24   AAPL  115.169998
> 2020-11-25   AAPL  116.029999
> 2020-11-23    AIR   27.890000
> 2020-11-24    AIR   29.540000
> 2020-11-25    AIR   29.510000
> ```

2. The normal (non-log) return

   `df['return'] = df.groupby(['ticker'])['adjclose'].pct_change()`

> ```
>            ticker    adjclose    return
> date                                   
> 2020-11-23   AAPL  113.849998       NaN
> 2020-11-24   AAPL  115.169998  0.011594
> 2020-11-25   AAPL  116.029999  0.007467
> 2020-11-23    AIR   27.890000       NaN
> 2020-11-24    AIR   29.540000  0.059161
> 2020-11-25    AIR   29.510000 -0.001016
> ```

-> the results look fine

3. now log return

   as a quick test:

   `np.log(df['adjclose']/df['adjclose'].shift(1))`

> ```
> 2020-11-25         NaN
> 2020-11-24   -0.007439
> 2020-11-23   -0.011528
> 2020-11-25   -1.350153
> 2020-11-24    0.001016
> 2020-11-23   -0.057477
> ```

seems to work in principle...

Now let's group it by ticker and store the result in a new column

```
`df['log_return'] = np.log(df.groupby(['ticker'])['adjclose'] / df.groupby(['ticker'])['adjclose'].shift(1))`
```

I get an error:
`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,2) (6,)`

Can somehow help me on this topic?
Thank you very much

Comment: Instead of grouping by ticker consider setting a multi index on date and ticker. I think that would solve your problem and probably execute faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this where we apply the log return calc to each `d` which is the group in the groupby:

```
df.groupby('ticker').apply(lambda d: d.assign(log_return = np.log(d['adjclose'] / d['adjclose'].shift(1)) ))
```

output

```
            date        ticker  adjclose    log_return
ticker                  
AAPL    2   2020-11-23  AAPL    113.849998  NaN
        1   2020-11-24  AAPL    115.169998  0.011528
        0   2020-11-25  AAPL    116.029999  0.007439
AIR     5   2020-11-23  AIR     27.890000   NaN
        4   2020-11-24  AIR     29.540000   0.057477
        3   2020-11-25  AIR     29.510000   -0.001016
```