# Unreliable result while calculating ETL in PerformanceAnalytics R package

Tags: python, r, dataframe, mathematical-optimization, performanceanalytics

I have a data frame something like this.

```
        Date  IOC.NS RELIANCE.NS  BPCL.NS HINDPETRO.NS EXIDEIND.NS    portfolio
0 2002-07-02 0.001000 -0.016930 0.001264 0.009413    0.055980     0.010145
1 2002-07-03 -0.000500 0.003931 -0.003787 0.015961    0.077108     0.018543
2 2002-07-04 -0.000500 -0.004289 0.007964 -0.006884    0.008949     0.001048
3 2002-07-05 0.005001 -0.013858 0.022266 0.012620    0.033259     0.011858
4 2002-07-08 -0.003235 0.032472 -0.001405 0.010356    0.072961     0.022230
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
5006 2022-08-22 -0.011781 -0.002774 -0.013599 -0.064657 -0.036829    -0.025928
5007 2022-08-23 -0.003506 0.015422 0.000150 -0.017028 0.012962    0.001600
5008 2022-08-24 -0.007037 -0.002664 -0.012436 -0.018767 0.009597    -0.006261
5009 2022-08-25 0.012757 -0.002917 0.000759 0.013451 0.001584     0.005127
5010 2022-08-26 0.006298 -0.003704 0.002881 0.003733 0.020563     0.005954
```

I scraped the daily closed data of these stocks and then calculated the pct_change() in python. And then made a equal-weighted portfolio.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
from scipy.stats import norm, t
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statistics


def getData(stocks, start, end):
    stockData = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stocks, start=start, end=end)
    stockData = stockData['Close']
    returns_pctchange = stockData.pct_change()
    return returns_pctchange

stockList = ['IOC', 'RELIANCE', 'BPCL', 'HINDPETRO', 'EXIDEIND']
stocks = [stock+'.NS' for stock in stockList]
endDate = dt.datetime.now()
startDate = endDate - dt.timedelta(days=8000)

returns = getData(stocks, start=startDate, end=endDate)
returns = returns.dropna()
weights = np.array([1/len(stocks) for n in stocks])
returns['portfolio'] = returns.dot(weights)
returns.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

After getting the returns dataframe, I wanted to calculate the monthly Value at Risk(VaR) and Expected Tail Risk(ETL) of the portfolio column using the R package [PerformanceAnalytics](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/index.html).

This was the code I had written to perform that.

```
df = read.csv('C:/Users/VaR and CVaR/returns')

ss = data.frame(`Month/Year`=unique(format(as.Date(df$Date),"%b/%Y")),
                `Monthly Expected Shortfall`=(tapply(df$portfolio,sub("-..$","",df$Date),FUN=PerformanceAnalytics::ETL)),
                check.names=F,row.names=NULL)
```

This basically group pct_change() of portfolio column of each day of a particular month and group them and then apply the **ETL** function from PerformanceAnalytics hence I get back the ETL of each month.

But I got one error like this.

```
ES calculation produces unreliable result (risk over 100%) for column: 1 : 4.05194174741596
```

When I searched about this problem, in many places, it was suggested to use the log returns, which is the same as pct_change(). [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31287552/logarithmic-returns-in-pandas-dataframe)

I could not understand where my mistake was and how to overcome the error it showed.

Please help me with this.

Comment: This doesn't look like a log return vs arithmetic returns issue (although it may happen for that too). There is most likely some error in the downloaded data where values are erroneously recorded. I've downloaded your data set (using quantmod). There seems to be some issue with the data on 28-July-2005.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out :) I figured it out just couple of days back.